# No "Displays" in System Preferences

Tags: macos, display-settings, system-preferences

Apparently I don't have the option to configure my displays in Mac OS X. The option "Displays" has been removed from the System Preferences.

Is there a way to restore this?

Comment: Is there a `Displays.prefPane` file in `/System/Library/PreferencePanes`? What happens when you open it?

Comment: If there's not, consider running the Combo Updater for your version of OS X (Google e.g. "10.6.7 combo update") before doing major surgery.

Comment: The file didn't exist. I've copied the file from another computer and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas I'll post as an answer so you can accept it. It will give us both a few reputation points and it will mark this question answered.

Comment: @thomas: If you copied it from another computer, you should probably finish up by running Repair Permissions in Disk Utility, to make sure the file's ownership gets set properly.  (This probably doesn't matter in this particular case, but is generally a good idea after messing with system files "by hand".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Displays.prefPane` exists and can be opened.

---

If it doesn't exist, run the Mac OS X combo update installer, or copy the Preference pane from another Mac running the same version of Mac OS X.

Comment: If you copied it from another computer, you should probably finish up by running Repair Permissions in Disk Utility, to make sure the file's ownership gets set properly.

Comment: @Gordon Does the user get notified of your comment here? Better comment on the question, just in case.